# Download image as thumbnail in listview adapter android

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, thumbnails

I have a decent android app which is using two fragments one of them is Listfragment. And my question is, can I use Asynctask to download the image and compress it to a thumbnail and then assign it to an imageview ? (Imagine there are like 100 items in ListView). Or is this even possible to call the asynctask each time ?

Comment: it's a very bad idea to start developing your own image downloading mechanism when there are so many out there which deal with all the problems around this, and have been tested a lot. I would recommend looking into Volley, I've had very good experience with this library, especially for downloading & downscaling images.

Comment: Yes. All what you want is possible. And a good exercise and good expierience to discover the flaws of the recycling views mechanism. You will not regret it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to reinvent the wheel. There are libraries which already can download, cache and resize image for you. For instance [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/):

```
Picasso
    .with(context)
    .load(url)
    .resizeDimen(width, height)
    .centerCrop()
    .error(R.drawable.error_img);
    .into(placeholder);
```

Comment: this is so cool, thanks man. gonna accept the question if it will work

Answer (score 0):

For this task, I would strongly recommend the use of an external library.

There are [many to choose from](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/46) that can be used to download, display and cache images from an online source. As many of these libraries have been developed for many years, they are *usually* going to be better than any bespoke code you write.